# subtotal issue in microstrategy

Tags: reporting, subtotal, microstrategy

Data in reports shown in below

```
id        name     standard changes scheduled changes

1          Sid        6                            5

2          Sid        6                            5

3          Sid        6                            5

4          Sid        6                            5
```

the above grid i am able to create in microstrategy. Based on the above data i have to create below data in the same report.

Total changes               44

Standard changes        27  61%

Scheduled changes       17  39%

How to achieve this. kindly assist me.

Comment: Could you please explain how are 27% and 17% calculated ?

Comment: please show also an example of the output you wish to have

Answer (score 0):

If you are on web you can create a new metric with the sum ( standard changes )and one with sum (scheduled changes) , also if you want to express in percent you need to create another two metrics with same calculation but expressed in % .